# How to select an item of mx:ComboBox on the basis of substring entered through keyboard

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I am using `<mx:ComboBox />` and I want to select a matching item on the basis of string entered through keyboard. Currently, `<mx:ComboBox />` selects the first matching item based on the first character only. I want this functionality to be customized. I am unable to find that KeyboardEvent listener which does the matching so that I can override it.

Comment: You have to override the ComboBox, there will be a text field:IUItextField (Something similar ) in the ComboBox class, you have to add Keylisteners to this to override, there are a lot of libraries which does this type of operation, please research it as it involves a lot of code.

Comment: Are you looking for "Type ahead" or "AutoComplete" functionality?  The Flextras MX AutoCompleteComboBox has both: http://www.flextras.com/?event=ProductHome&productID=19

Comment: @Zeus Kindly give me some of the references.

Comment: It would be very helpful if someone guide me to develop my own custom `ComboBox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this yourself, you should look at the following bits and pieces of code below from the `ComboBox` and `ListBase` classes. `ListBase` is what the `ComboBox` component uses for it's drop down list.

The `ComboBox` appears to be deferring the keyboard input to the drop down list. It then listens for events from the drop down list to know when the selection has changed (as a result of keyboard or mouse input).

Flex components usually override a method called `keyDownHandler()` to process the keyboard input when they have focus. Starting there, we come across [ComboBox line 2231](https://github.com/apache/flex-sdk/blob/develop/frameworks/projects/mx/src/mx/controls/ComboBox.as#L2231):

```
// Redispatch the event to the dropdown
// and let its keyDownHandler() handle it.

dropdown.dispatchEvent(event.clone());
event.stopPropagation();
```

So now the `keyDownHandler()` in the drop down list will get executed. That method has a giant `switch` statement, where the `default` case statement [on line 9197 of ListBase](https://github.com/apache/flex-sdk/blob/develop/frameworks/projects/mx/src/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.as#L9197) looks like this:

```
default:
{
    if (findKey(event.charCode))
        event.stopPropagation();
}
```

This is where the drop down list decides what to select based on keyboard input (when the input is not an arrow key or page up, etc.). The protected `findKey()` method simply calls the public `findString()` method to do this work.

So to override this behavior yourself:

- extend the `ListBase` class and override the `findKey()` or `findString()` methods with your custom logic
- extend `ComboBox` class and override the `createChildren()` method so you can instantiate your custom `ListBase` class instead of the default one.

Comment: Thanks for the great insight of what is happening in `keyDownHandler()`. I have found an easy solution for my case which I'm posting here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the class which I've used in order to make it work. `searchStr` is user inputted string which needs to be matched. If no dataprovider item gets matched to the `searchStr`, the overridden listener falls back to the default behaviour. I am using `Timer` to flush the inputted `searchStr` after 2 seconds. The possible drawback is that it is assuming the dataprovider to be a collection of `String` values. But you can modify it accordingly as the need may be.

```
public class CustomComboBox extends ComboBox
    {
        private var searchStr:String="";
        private var ticker:Timer;
        public function CustomComboBox()
        {
            super();
            ticker = new Timer(2000);
            ticker.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, resetSearchString);
        }

        override protected function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            super.keyDownHandler(event);

            // code to search items in the list based on user input.
            // Earlier, the default behavior shows the matched items in the dropdown,  based on first character only.
            // user input is invisible to user.
            if((event.charCode>=0x20 && event.charCode<=0x7E) || event.charCode==8)             //Range of printable characters is 0x20[space] to 0x7E[~] in ASCII. 8 is ASCII code of [backspace].
            {
                ticker.reset();
                ticker.start();

                if(event.charCode==8)
                {
                    if(searchStr=="")
                        return;
                    searchStr = searchStr.substr(0, searchStr.length-1);
                }
                else
                {
                    searchStr += String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
                    searchStr = searchStr.toLowerCase();
                }
                for each(var str:String in dataProvider)
                {
                    if(str.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchStr, 0)>-1)
                    {
                        this.selectedItem = dropdown.selectedItem = str;
                        dropdown.scrollToIndex(dropdown.selectedIndex);

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        /**
         * reset the search string and reset the timer.
         **/ 
        private function resetSearchString(evt:TimerEvent):void
        {
            searchStr = "";
            ticker.reset();
        }
    }
```